# Social link in header

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a TikTok logo to the top right of the page. I think the culprit is "display: flex" but if I remove it, my other texts get messed up. How do I move the TikTok logo to the top right of the page? Thanks in advance for your help!

[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5wG.jpg)

```css
.hero {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 88vh;
  display: flex;  /*messes up placement of tiktok logo */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  /* Background styles */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(xxx);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;   
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="header">
        <a class="social-icon-header" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@">
            <img class="tiktok-logo" src="images/tiktok_logo_png_transparent512 (1).png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay">
        <h1> Get clear skin! </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use font awesome not images to use the logo of any popular website.

Comment: Hi @AliMustafa — out of curiosity, why should I use font awesome and not images for logos? There was only 1 version of the TikTok logo on font awesome and it didn't look that...awesome.

Comment: You should always use an svg instead of an image because images become blurry or pixelated but svg doesn't. All the logos you see on amazing websites such as apple, twitter and Microsoft are svg's. If a user zooms in on your webpage, the pixels of your image logo will tear but in case of an SVG it won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try position:absolute for placing items over existing layout.

```css
.hero {
width: 100vw;
height: 88vh;
display: flex;  /*messes up placement of tiktok logo */
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;

/* Background styles */
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(xxx);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;   
position:relative;
}
.social-icon-header{
  position:absolute;
  top:1em;
  right:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="header">
        <a class="social-icon-header" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@">
            <img class="tiktok-logo" src="images/tiktok_logo_png_transparent512 (1).png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay">
        <h1> Get clear skin! </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

.header div is not needed if there's only one icon.

If more icons will be placed, replace .social-icon-header selector with .header

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Oh. I got it wrong. My mistake. I was too quick there. I thought you wanted it to look like the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5wG.jpg). That the logo is slightly offset downwards. Then my solution would be the right one.

But at the top right, it's `position:absolute;`. Just like **@saravanapriyan** has already answered correctly.

```
.social-icon-header{
  position:absolute;
  top:1em;
  right:1em;
}
```

### original answear

One quick solution would be to assign margin-top to the logo.

`.header { margin-top: 70px; }`

```css
.hero {
width: 100vw;
height: 88vh;
display: flex;  /*messes up placement of tiktok logo */
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;

/* Background styles */
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(xxx);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;   

}

.header {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="header">
        <a class="social-icon-header" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@">
            <img class="tiktok-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/000">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay">
        <h1> Get clear skin! </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Maik, I tried that but the tiktok logo didn't move at all

Comment: @tretuser Maybe update the browser cache. Otherwise, is there a problem with other styles? I don't have enough information for that. In the example it works.

Comment: @tretuser A quick fix might be to write the header style inline for a moment so you know it's working and it can't be something else. ` <div class="header" style="margin-top: 70px;">`